# BizTalk - Changing the admin and operators groups

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2006

I have a BizTalk 2006 (r1) implementation. This has two environments, UAT and Prod. Both are configured in the same way, two applications servers and a separate sql server (6 servers in total).

At the time the implementation was created (16 years ago!), both environments were configured with the same AD Groups for BizTalkAdminGroup and BizTalkOperators group. I would like to change the AD groups used by the UAT environment, so that developers have access to the UAT instance of the BizTalk admin console without having access to that in Prod.

My first thought was to update this via the BizTalk Configuration app but when I tried this in a sandbox instance it led to a dead BizTalk environment - as suggested [at this technet link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33650.biztalk-how-to-manually-reconfigure-user-and-group-security-settings-without-deleting-databases.aspx)

So, I tried running the following t-sql update directly against the UAT instance of the BizTalkMgmt database:

```
UPDATE adm_Group
SET BizTalkAdminGroup = '<domain>\BizTalk UAT Server Administrators'
,BizTalkOperatorGroup = '<domain>\BizTalk UAT operators Group'
```

Although the update ran ok, it doesn't seem to have had the desired effect. A user that is a member of the UAT AD group but not the Prod group is unable to administer via the UAT instance of the BizTalk Admin Console.

Screencast [here](https://youtu.be/j41r638sobw)

I wonder if anyone else has solved this problem in the past?

Comment: Have you tried un-configuring BizTalk and then re-configuring it?

Comment: Hi Colin, yes that was my first thought but didn't have any luck. I've just made a short screencast to better explain the problem: https://youtu.be/j41r638sobw